# Virtualbox forward specific ip to guest

Tags: php, ubuntu-12.04, virtualbox

I have a dedicated server with `Ubuntu 13.10` installed and a basic installation with `Virtualbox` and `phpvirtualbox` to manage the guest OSs on it. I have two IP addresses pointing to the server and I would like to use one of them purely for a virtual OS I have with `Ubuntu 12.04` on it.

This means that every port etc. would pass through the host server and be forwarded straight on to this guest OS.

I have looked at the different network methods on VirtualBox but none seem to be for me.

If I use NAT and port forwarding I can set the guest PC to only register calls to those ports through that 2nd IP which is great. However I cant use any standard ports that already are in use on the host PC like SSH or 80 as the host PC uses them on both IPs

How can I get the host OS to just pass everything through to a specific guest OS for a specific IP?

Have I done this wrong and I need to use a different hosting type?

**EDIT:**

From research and comments it seems bridging should be the way forward but again i am stuck, here is my /etc/network/interfaces file..

```
# Loopback device:
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# device: eth0
auto  eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address   1.2.3.4
  broadcast 1.2.3.5
  netmask   255.255.255.200
  gateway   1.2.3.1
  # default route to access subnet
  up route add -net 1.2.3.6 netmask 255.255.255.220 gw 1.2.3.1 eth0

iface eth0 inet6 static
  address 2a01:4f8:161:9442::2
  netmask 64
  gateway fe80::1

  #create bridge using additional IP
  auto br1
    iface br1 inet static
    address 2.3.4.5
    netmask 255.255.255.220
    gateway 2.3.4.1
    broadcast 2.3.4.7
    bridge_ports br1 vbox0 vbox1
```

The server is a Hetzner EX with an additional IP thats on the same MAC address (i can get a different MAC from them if needs be?)

With the above settings i set my Win7 guest OS to be bridged to br1 and set the ip in windows to be static with the same settings i.e.

```
address 2.3.4.5
netmask 255.255.255.220
gateway 2.3.4.1
```

But it couldnt pick up a network

Lastly i have added to /etc/vbox/interfaces:

```
vbox0 vbox br1
vbox1 vbox br1
```

Comment: Why don't you just bridge the NIC instead of NAT'ing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked this question on askubuntu.com here

https://askubuntu.com/questions/409862/virtualbox-forward-specific-ip-to-guest

Mods, feel free to delete one or t'other!

Here is the way o solved the problem though

After a LOT of trial and error, this seems to be the most reliable option...

http://wiki.hetzner.de/index.php/Netzkonfiguration_Debian/en#Bridged

> Bridged With a bridged configuration, packets are sent directly. The
>   guest system behaves as if independent. As this makes the MAC
>   addresses of the guest system visible from the outside, a virtual MAC
>   address needs to be requested via the Hetzner Robot and assigned to
>   the guest network card. The bridge gets the same network configuration
>   as eth0. The configuration of eth0 is omitted without replacement.

Get seperate MAC addresses for each of the additional IPs

Then use this for the hosts /etc/network/interfaces..

```
# remove or disable configuration for eth0
#auto eth0
#iface eth0 inet static
#
auto  br0
iface br0 inet static
 address (Main IP)
 netmask (like eth0, e.g: 255.255.255.254)
 gateway (same as that for the main IP)
 bridge_ports eth0
 bridge_stp off
 bridge_fd 1
 bridge_hello 2
 bridge_maxage 12
```

Set up the Guest OS in virtualbox to use a bridged network and select br0, then in advanced settings set the mac of the network adapter to the MAC address that Hetzner gave you for the new IP (without any :)

Then in the Guest OS use this..

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
#iface eth0 inet dhcp

iface eth0 inet static
address (ADD IP 1)
broadcast (FOR ADD IP 1)
netmask (FOR ADD IP 1)
gateway (MAIN IP)
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest enabling bridging instead of using NAT.

EDIT:

BUT if you're stuck using NAT you can use iptables:

`iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -d VMIPADDRESS -p tcp --sport PORTTOFORWARD --dport DESTINATIONPORT -j ACCEPT`

`iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT`

ALSO, enable ipv4 forwarding:

`echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

EDIT:

Try this:

```
# Loopback device:
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# device: eth0
auto  eth0
iface eth0 inet manual


iface eth0 inet6 static
  address 2a01:4f8:161:9442::2
  netmask 64
  gateway fe80::1

  #create bridge using additional IP
  auto br0
    iface br0 inet static
    address 2.3.4.5
    netmask 255.255.255.220
    gateway 2.3.4.1
    broadcast 2.3.4.7
    bridge_ports eth0 vbox0 vbox1
    up route add -net 1.2.3.6 netmask 255.255.255.220 gw 1.2.3.1 br0
```

Comment: Thanks, i have since learnt that bridging is probably the right way forward, i just cant work it out... i have edited my question to show my etc/network/interfaces file, i would appreciate it if anybody could see if its correct and if so, what settings i should have on my guest OS (win7 and ubuntu headless)

Comment: This article should still be applicable: http://codesupply.net/content/setup-bridged-networking-virtualbox-ubuntu-1110

Make sure you did a `sudo apt-get install uml-utilities bridge-utils` and that your eth0 is set to manual instead of static. Remove the IP of eth0 and apply it instead to br1. A bridged interface is still an interface with an IP, etc. It will, however, wreak havoc with network-manager, or whatever and will extend the boot time by ~2+ minutes unless you disable network manager or find another fix.

Comment: I still have no luck with this, Is my setup correct (added above) for a bridged interface? If i add a win7 guest os and then attach that to br1, then set the ip address manually to "2.3.4.5" etc then it says IP address conflict?? I would just like to know if i even have the host set up correctly then worry about the guest OSes!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NAT` with `Port Forwarding`, in order to pass all connection from Host OS to Guest OS.

You will need to edit Virtual Machine network setting, Set Network Adapter to NAT and Edit port forwarding option.
In Port forwarding option of VM, specify which port you want to forward,

For example,

If want SSH port, then specify

```
Name : SSH 
Protocol : TCP 
Host IP : <your host ip>
Host Port : <your host SSH port>
Guest IP : <your guest ip>
Guest Port : <your guest port>
```

Comment: Thanks but this causes a problem with ports already in use on the host ip.. i.e port 22 for SSH, even if i set the hosts SSH to only listen on one IP, the other ip doesnt get passed through to the guest PC